# How to stretch points?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stretching

Let say I've 5 points, where p0 and p4 are fixed with values 0.0 and 4.0:

```
0 | 1.0 | 2.0 | 3.0 | 4
```

The points in the middle can change, but they must stretch the others once moving.

So for a `stretch` "to right", it must `enlarge` the prev values around the moving point and `press` the next ones between the moving point and the last point, keeping the proportions between each points.

I've write this [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/48b106d1d9023e00) which move the 3° point to `2.5` from its original `2.0` x-position:

```
const int numPoints = 5;
double points[numPoints] = { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };

int stretchedPoint = 2;
double prevX = points[stretchedPoint];
points[stretchedPoint] = 2.5;

std::cout<< points[0];
for (int prevPoint = 1; prevPoint < numPoints - 1; prevPoint++) {
    // prev points
    if (prevPoint < stretchedPoint) {
        double ratio = points[stretchedPoint] / prevX;
        points[prevPoint] *= ratio;
    // next points
    } else if (prevPoint > stretchedPoint) {
        double ratio = (points[numPoints - 1] - prevX) / (points[numPoints - 1] - points[stretchedPoint]);
        points[prevPoint] *= ratio;
    }

    std::cout << " | " << points[prevPoint];
}
std::cout << " | " << points[numPoints - 1];
```

which give to me right result for prev points:

```
0 | 1.25 | 2.5 | 0.76 | 4
```

but when I try to apply the "same-wrapped-math" for the next points, I get a non-proportional scaling, which give weird results (`4`?)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot about non-zero starting point

```
 points[prevPoint] = points[stretchedPoint] + ratio * (points[prevPoint] - prevX)
```

Note that same logic should be applied to previos points, if start value is non-zero

In general, to apply linear interpolation for initial `X0..X1` interval and final `X0new..X1ne`w interval, one have to use

```
 (Xnew - X0new) / (X1new - X0new) = (X - X0) / (X1 - X0)
 so
 XNew = X0new + (X1new - X0new) * (X - X0) / (X1 - X0)
```

Comment: Uhm, which ratio do you use? 0.96 now here http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5671e6fbfba8419

Comment: 3,25 is wrong anyway! The proportional is not kept.

Comment: your coliru example uses 0.1 0.2 0.3 values instead of 1,2,3.  3.25 is middle between 2.5 and 4 like 3 was middle between 2 and 4 - proportionality preserves

Comment: Yes, but see the A.S.H  answer: it should be `2.53947` (duality on stretching).

Comment: It is true for 0.1 0.2 0.3 input data:  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cb243e3b41095346     `0 | 1.25 | 2.5 | 2.53947 | 4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142072/discussion-between-paizza-and-mbo).

Answer (score 1):

What you did on the left side of the point (and which is working) can be rewritten somehow like this:

```
//  double ratio = (points[stretchedPoint] - 0) / (prevX - 0);
//  points[prevPoint] = 0 + ratio * (points[prevPoint] - 0);
```

To achieve exactly the dual on the right side, it should be:

```
} else if (prevPoint > stretchedPoint) {
    double ratio = (points[numPoints - 1] - points[stretchedPoint]) /
         (points[numPoints - 1] - prevX);
    points[prevPoint] = points[numPoints - 1] -
        ratio * (points[numPoints-1] - points[prevPoint]);
}
```

Comment: Your algo seems to works perfect. Is the "linear interpolation" formula suggested by @MBo? p.s. warning to `points[prevPoint])` typo

Comment: Well in fact, yes, it is the correct linear transformation. Also not that to start with any point on the left side instead of zero, you can take the commented code and replace `0` by `points[0]`